# Devise and current_page?

Tags: ruby, haml, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4 app i use devise to authenticate my users and i've setup a custom nav bar creator using HAML and the application_helper.rb. The code in the helper uses current_page to decide where to add an 'active' class to the HTML element because im using the twitter bootstrap. Now everything i've said works fine such as when you go to the root of the site the button in the bar is active (pushed in) but if you click on another item in the bar and go to a pag such as /sig_in/ you get sent to the page but the button for that page is not active. Im not sure wether this is a devise or ruby problem. Here is my code:

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :path => ''
```

_nav.html.haml

```
= navigation_link_to 'Home', root_path

/ Insert Additional Nav

= navigation_link_to 'Sign in', new_user_session_path
```

application_helper.rb

```
 def navigation_link_to(text, path)
    link_to text, path, class: "btn#{active_link(path)}"
  end

  def active_link(path)
    ' active' if current_page?(path)
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this is working quite well (I use 3.0.0.rc devise gem in Rails 4)

In routes.rb only:

```
devise_for :users
```

I have a `_login.html.haml` which is inserted in `_navigation.html.haml`. Path helpers provided by Devise automatically. If user already signed in then different links will be appeared.

```
%li=link_to 'Registration', new_user_registration_path
%li=link_to 'Sign in', new_user_session_path unless user_signed_in?
-if user_signed_in?
   %li=link_to 'Manage your registration', edit_user_registration_path
   %li=link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete
```